# Is there an equivalent of sequence generator (in informatica)in talend?

Tags: talend

I have a need to generate sequence like below

Today load:

Id. Name

1. Aama
2. Abba
   03 acca

Tomorrow

Id. Name

1. Aama
2. Abba
   03 acca
   04.Bcca

So basically the sequence has to be maintained for consecutive runs as well.
Numeric routine didn't work as everytime it started the number that I gave.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: System.out.println(Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1));

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the data from previous run ? If so, you'll have to get this last number, then with Numeric.sequence, you can use `Numeric.sequence(row1.lastInsertID,1,1)` (with row1.lastInsertID being the max ID of your last run).